# Sweetalert: e2e testing using Protractor

Tags: protractor, sweetalert

I am trying to test my web application which uses SweetAlert. I am using Protractor for e2e testing.

When I tried selecting an element using

`var textElement = element(by.id("newWbName"));`

protractor goes into an infinite loop, saying

`W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, *[id="newWbName"]) - the first result will be used`

as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZcsRq), even though there is only one id with `newWbName`.

I am wondering if there is anything in how sweet alert renders the alert that is causing this issue?  The selectors work fine when I use them on the rest of the page.  Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more than one ID with that name on the page?  If you go into the browser inspector, and do a search for `newWbName`, it says there is only 1?

Comment: In devtools console, if I type `$("#newWbName")`, I get `jQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#newWbName"}` (which of course,  can be expanded and inspected further)

Comment: Update: I did `search` for `newWbName`, and it's showing up two instances so you were right. Thanks for pointing that. I will investigate why it's adding two ids. Will update soon

Comment: I figured it out, apparently sweet alert was creating two same blocks of code. One on initialization, and one when actual alert was present. I narrowed down my selector further, and that did the trick. Thank you so much again, for suggesting the search for the id.

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped.